# Adding a texture on the mesh Libgdx

Tags: opengl, libgdx, mesh

I am just starting out with Libgdx and having a problem adding a texture on a mesh. I can't find a working example, so I am asking for a few code snippets demonstrating rendering a mesh with a texture.

Comment: Try the Libgdx wiki: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/MeshColorTexture.  That is the first hit for a google search for: libgdx example mesh texture

Comment: Yes, but it is deprecated.

Comment: It should mostly still apply.  What specifically isn't working for you?

Comment: It renders [this](http://imgur.com/Pl2lbBe). It doesn't render the texture, although it flashes the texture for one frame just as it starts. I am quite certain that the shaders are ok.

Comment: If i remove `Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);` it renders a solid white triangle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new 3d api (only in the nightlies builds right now), you should check this: http://blog.xoppa.com/ made by the man who is working on the api right now. From using the model-meshbuilder, to loading models, adding textures and rendering shaders.